# getIntExtra always returns the default value

Tags: android

I am trying to pass an integer between activities using an intent. 
The source activity makes the calls info.id is the selected item from 
a ListView.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, newClass.class); 
intent.putExtra("selectedItem", info.id); 
this.startActivity(intent);
```

The target activity retrieves the intent using getIntent then calls

```
int iSelectedItem = intent.getIntExtra("selectedItem", -1);
```

iSelectedItem is always -1 instead of the value passed to putExtra. 
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or do I misunderstand the 
use of intents?

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that info.id will be a 'long' and is not converting to an 'int'. Try

```
long iSelectedItem = intent.getLongExtra("selectedItem", -1)
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't find `putIntExtra()` method. So I ended up with following:

```
intent.putExtra("jobId", 1);
```

and

```
Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("jobId").ToString());
```

Use try and catch to handle Exceptions.

**UPDATE**

Later I found that I was passing jobId as a string in `putExtra()` method, therefore `getIntExtra()` was always returning the default value.

So @Grant is correct. You **must** pass an Integer value in `putExtra()` method to use `getIntExtra()` method.

Comment: When you say "You must pass an Integer value" does that mean the `Integer` object or the integer `int` native?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was a simple thing.

Check if you're using onActivityResult ... than, you don't have
to use getIntent() to get the extras, you have to use the intent
you pass as parameter.

In your case should be something like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int iSelectedItem = intent.getIntExtra("selectedItem", -1);             
        Log.d("DEBUG", "check iSelectedItem = " + iSelectedItem);
    }
}
```

observe that I'm not using getIntent(), but the argument intent.

(PS: if you're calling a lot of activities expecting results, is better to check if the intent is != null)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int iSelectedItem = bundle.getInt("selectedItem", -1);
```

Now, if you're using StartActivityForResult and you want to return some data, from the child activity, remind that you have to use onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    int iSelectedItem = intent.getExtras.getInt("selectedItem", -1);             
    Log.d("DEBUG", "check iSelectedItem = " + iSelectedItem);
  }
}
```

Remember, is the same way like you get extras from other Activity, just using bundle.getInt, in this example, getExtras return a bundle, so, across this bundle, you can get any data that you have sent from the resultIntent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I created the object with mId member variable declared as string

```
public class Application {

private String mId;
....
}

intent.putExtra("id", myApplication.getId());
```

and as such, the Extra is passed as string. simply change your member variable to int, you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int sub_menu_id = 0;
    int question_part = 0;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            sub_menu_id = -1;
            question_part = -1;
        } else {
            sub_menu_id = extras.getInt("sub_menu_id");
            question_part = extras.getInt("question_part");
        }
    }

    Log.d("DREG", "sub_menu_id: " + sub_menu_id + "\nquestion_part: " + question_part);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I converted the value inside putExtra to String from Int and Long and while receiving, received it as String only. Can't figure out why but Integer, Long were showing `defaultValues` while after converting to String it works.

Example :

```
intent.putExtra("code", response.data?.code.toString())
```

```
val code = intent.getStringExtra("code")
```